# IValueConverter to convert 4 digit int to time(date)

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to write a `Converter` using the `IValueConverter`.

What I am trying to do is allow the user to type a number in a `DataGRid` anywhere 1 to 4 digits and have that represent a time in 24 hours time format.

This is the code I have so far, When testing with dummy values in a dummy method (NOT the converter), it return the desired date + time.

```
public class ReturnDateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DateTime result = new DateTime();
        var param = parameter as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(param) || value == null) return result;
        if (param.Length > 4) return result;
        var date = DateTime.Parse(value.ToString());
        var pad = param.PadLeft(4, '0');
        string[] t = pad.Select(s => s.ToString()).ToArray();
        var newTime = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(t[0] + t[1]), int.Parse(t[2] + t[3]), 0);
        if (newTime.Minutes == 1) return result;
        var timestring = date.Date + newTime;
        result = timestring;
        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And the XAML,

```
<UserControl.Resources>        
    <local:ReturnDateConverter x:Key="ReturnDateConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>


<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="退勤" Width="90" SortMemberPath="Date_Data">
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TimeDataTwo, StringFormat={}{0:hh:mm}, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
          </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <xctk:DateTimeUpDown Minimum="{Binding Path=TimeDataTwo}"
                                         Maximum="{Binding Path=TimeDataTwo,
                                         Converter={StaticResource ReturnDateConverter},
                                         ConverterParameter=1}" 
                                         Format="ShortTime" 
                                         Value="{Binding Path=TimeDataTwo,
                                         StringFormat={}{0:hh:mm}, 
                                         UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
               </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The converter fires but, I always seem to get `minvalue` for the `DataTime`  in the result and it exits the code on this line`if (newTime.Minutes == 1) return result;` due to no value being present.

Any help would be appreciated.

### EDIT:

without changing the question due there already being an answer, I took out the `ConverterParameter=1` and now I just get a `null` value here `var param = parameter as string;`???

Comment: Your converter parameter argument is always 1.  No user input is used to create time value.  So do not see how you can expect result to be anything other than min date.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your code and execute it step by step, you'll quickly see what's wrong

Comment: @KevinGosse, I have stepped through the code for the last 4 hours.

Comment: I am going to have to go back to the drawing board, I am too far from a near working example. Until then this question is has an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First issue**

You pass a `ConverterParameter=1` to your converter and parse this one instead of the `value`.

**update**

Looking at the possibilities `DateTimeUpDown` offers, you could try `AllowTextInput` and specify a `Format="Custom"` with you desired format string:

```
<xctk:DateTimeUpDown Format="Custom" 
                     FormatString="H:mm"
                     AllowTextInput="true" 
                     Value="{Binding Path=TimeDataTwo, StringFormat={}{0:hh:mm}, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
```

I would definitely throw out

```
Minimum="{Binding Path=TimeDataTwo}"
Maximum="{Binding Path=TimeDataTwo}"
```

because it doesn't really make sense to set the min and max to the current value thus making any editing impossible.

**Second issue:**

If you want 24 hours format, you need to use the `HH` format picture - `hh` is the 12 hour one.

Change

```
StringFormat={}{0:hh:mm}
```

to

```
StringFormat={}{0:HH:mm}
```

---

See [MSDN - Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Took out `ConverterParameter=1` and changed format, now the converter does not fire???, Sorry meant to say, there is no value.

Comment: I meant to say, there is no value, it is null now.

Comment: UV for the help, as it does answer part of my issue.

Comment: Your Xaml looks like your Converter is stuck inside the `Maximum` property of your `DateTimeUpDown` - check the opening `{` and closing `}` of your properties and maybe update your code here to reflect your current code.

Comment: Yeah, I am going to have to re-evaluate what I have done, moving the converter out of `Maximum` is giving me funny results. I changed to `Value` as well. Now everything is out of wack. I am marking this solved until I can get a bit closer to a working example.